# Jquery :not not working with id

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a dropdown menu, so that when anywhere on the page but the dropdown menu or the links leading to them are clicked, the dropdown is hidden.
Jquery:

```
$('body:not(#top-links-bar)').click(function(){
   $('.dropdown').hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="top-links-bar">

    <span  class="top-link link-bar-link " style="font-size:20pt; border:inherit;border-radius:inherit;"></span>

    <span class="top-link link-bar-link dropdown-opener" id="learn">Link One <span class="caret"></span></span>



    <span class="top-link link-bar-link dropdown-opener" id="stories-link">Link Two<span class="caret"></span></span>

    <span class="top-link link-bar-link" id="tutorials-and-snippets">Link Three<span class="caret"></span></span>

    <!---<span class="top-link link-bar-link dropdown-opener" id="affiliate-content">Link Four <span class="caret"></span></span>--->

    <a href="" style="color:blue;" style="position:relative; right:50px; top:20px;"><span class="top-link link-bar-link" id="login" >Link Five</span></a>

<a href="" style="color:blue;" style="position:relative; right:100px; top:20px;"><span class="top-link link-bar-link" id="create-account"  >Link Six</span></a>



    </div>
    <div id="learn-dropdown" class="dropdown" style="font-weight:bold;">
    <p style="font-size:20pt;">HTML and CSS
    <ul>
    <li> <a href="learn/learn-html">The Basics</a></li>
    </ul>
    </p>
    <p style="font-size:20pt;">Javascript</p>
    </div>
    <div id="affiliate-content-dropdown" class="dropdown">
   </div>   
    <div id="snippet-dropdown" class="dropdown">
   </div>
    <div id="stories-dropdown" class="dropdown">
    </div>
```

I have other code that makes the dropdowns actually drop down. With this code, the dropdowns stay hidden. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yak613/614eyqt1/6/),
and [**site**](http://sarkelliancreed.comule.com)

Comment: Use `$('body *:not(...)')`

Comment: That didn't work at all. That is, the jquery didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There issues in the selecor you checking for the body without id top-links-bar this false every time  try this

```
    $('body div:not(#top-links-bar)').click(function () {
        $('.dropdown').hide();
    });
```

I think you go with the below comment

Try this

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#top-links-bar').length) {
        $('.dropdown').hide();
    }
});
```

or try this

```
 $('body').click(function(e){
        if (!$(e.target).parents('#top-links-bar').length) {
            $('.dropdown').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: No; he wants to handle non-`div`s too.

Comment: What happens when you don't click on a div? This is not very flexible. And you are binding click to all divs instead of just body http://jsfiddle.net/614eyqt1/9/  or Xin's answer is the better way to go

Comment: Here is an example of this not working, http://jsfiddle.net/614eyqt1/11/ this answer requires everything to be wrapped in a div

Comment: in this html code everything is wrapped with div only

Comment: I got it working now, but when I try to put the same code in another file, it _doesn't_ work. Any reason why?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, that's not what the :not selector does unfortunately. The selector is selecting the 'body' element only (and not the children of it) so your :not won't do anything there. [See the docs here](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

In your `click` function, you can just query the element, for example:

```
$('body').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('id') !== 'top-links-bar') {
        $('.dropdown').hide();
    }
});
```

EDIT: Above is wrong, actually, this will work. Thanks @SLaks and @Huangism:

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).closest().length) {
        $('.dropdown').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Check for `.closest('#top-links-bar').length` as well as the target id, which will cover clicking anywhere in and on the menu

Comment: Just do `!$(e.target).closest().length`

Answer (score 0):

You are not using :not correctly. try this:

jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/strannij/z5bhq9zz/6/][1]

```
$(document.body).children().not('#top-links-bar').click(function(){
$('.dropdown').hide();

});
```

Comment: Wrong.  His syntax is fine, and this won't work either.

Comment: No, the dropdowns don't appear then.

Comment: Yes, i forgat to add .children() method. Serves me right for typing to fast:)